# UIBlurEffect blurring text as well?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

So I added a `UIBlurEffect` to my view using this code

```
let visualEffectView2 = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
visualEffectView2.frame = bgIBO.bounds
abilityContainerIBO.addSubview(visualEffectView2)
```

Unfortunately, it also blurred the text inside the view. I figured I just needed to add vibrancy to the text

```
let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light)))
visualEffectView.frame = abilityTextIBO.bounds
abilityTextIBO.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```

But that produced no results. Why is the text getting blurred as well? It needs to be inside the `UIView` and not on top because the height of the `UIView` is dependent on the height of the text

What it looks like with the blur effect applied
[image]
The text is in the UIView but for some reason adding the blur effect blurred everything. The text is not visible

Comment: Any image for reference? How do you want your output?

Comment: And what you are getting from this code?

Comment: I can't see text. Where is it?

Comment: Try visualEffectView.alpha = 0.5

Comment: For sure, you're adding a view(blurview) onto your view, all objects in your main view (e.g. button , textView, imageView ..) will be covered with blurview.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wei Jay's comment. I found the answer. To achieve the effect, You need three views

[image]

I just created a `subview` of the initial `UIView` and applied the blurView to that.